# getting font cell and backcolor cell of a specific sheet of google spread sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google spread sheet, which has many sheets. I would like to get font color of a cell in a specific sheet.
I have found [this API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) but I cannot specify from which sheet. Do you have any idea with which API how can I do this job?

Comment: This should be easy when doing it via google apps script, will you consider scripting this issue?

Comment: It seems that I have no other chance. I am new in it. Would you please give more info about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Method: spreadsheets.get**](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

- includeGridData should be set to true
- input the cell or range of cells that you want to get

---

**Example:**

***Sheets:***

[image]

***Query Parameters:***

[image]

***Response Body:***

- Spreadsheets.get will return a [Resource:Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet), you can get the cell font color of your range requested under "[sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#Sheet)" -> "[data](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#GridData)" -> "[rowData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#RowData)" -> "[values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellData)" -> "[userEnteredFormat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellFormat)" -> "[textFormat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#TextFormat)" -> "[foregroundColor](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#Color)"

  ```
    "sheets": [
       {

      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "stringValue": "DONE"
                  },
                  "effectiveValue": {
                    "stringValue": "DONE"
                  },
                  "formattedValue": "DONE",
                  "userEnteredFormat": {
                    "textFormat": {
                      "foregroundColor": {
                        "red": 0.9843137,
                        "green": 0.7372549,
                        "blue": 0.015686275
                      },
                      "fontFamily": "Arial",
                      "foregroundColorStyle": {
                        "themeColor": "ACCENT3"
                      }
                    }
                  },

                  * * *    
        {
          "startRow": 1,
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "stringValue": "NOK"
                  },
                  "effectiveValue": {
                    "stringValue": "NOK"
                  },
                  "formattedValue": "NOK",
                  "userEnteredFormat": {
                    "textFormat": {
                      "foregroundColor": {
                        "red": 1,
                        "blue": 1
                      },
                      "fontFamily": "Arial",
                      "foregroundColorStyle": {
                        "rgbColor": {
                          "red": 1,
                          "blue": 1
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
    * **
  ```

  }

Your font color for Sheet1!A1 will be:

```
"foregroundColor": { "red": 0.9843137, "green": 0.7372549, "blue": 0.015686275 }
```

You need to convert the floating rgb value using this formula:

```
 Math.floor( floating color value * 255)
```

Based on this reference: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#Color

[image]

[image]